# Using Entity Framework 6 with Multiple DB Schemas but using One DBContext

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, db-schema

I have an application using EF as ORM. The database used to have one schema, dbo and everything was working fine. I recently organized my tables into 4 different schemas. Some tables of one schema have dependencies on tables that reside on a different schema. All seems to be valid on the SQL side.

On the app side all db interactions through EF are not working anymore. The code compiles, the schemas are visible in the solution, the model mappings point to the right schemas, but once I try to insert a row to a table it does not work.

I have seen a few posts about using multiple schemas will require using multiple DBContexts but I would rather use one DBContext. All my schemas have the same owner dbo and I do not see a reason of using multiple DBContexts.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this?

Comment: Check here http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/. You will manage all dbcontexts in one places.

Comment: I want to use one dbcontext!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can map each table to its own schema by fluent mapping only. In your `DbContext` subtype you should override `OnModelCreating` (if you haven't done so already) and add statements like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()  
    .ToTable("t_Department", "school");
```

Entities that you don't map like this explicitly will be placed in the default `dbo` schema, or you can provide your own default by

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("sales");
```

(summarized from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx))

Comment: I don't know if it changed in the meantime, or I was blatantly incorrect, but it's not fluent mapping *only*. You can also use data annotations,  `[Table("t_Department", Schema = "school")]`.

Comment: It didn't work with MySQL.

Answer (score 38):

In addition to the responce of Gert Arnold, you can also use Table attribute in your entity:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("t_Department", Schema = "school")]
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

@GertArnold is spot on with his answer. However for pure syntactic candy you can also do this via a convention to pull the schema from the namespace of your models. We found this useful dealing with multiple schemas

```
modelBuilder.Types().Configure(e => {
        var schema = e.ClrType.Namespace.Split('.').Last().ToLower();
        var name = entity.ClrType.Name;
        return entity.ToTable(name, schema);
});
```

the above will take the final component of the namespace and use it as the schema name. This avoids the need for customising the table binding for every entity.

Comment: Could you elaborate or give a more complete example?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it's possibly that I use DB First to generate my EDMX file, so it doesn't invoke `OnModelCreating` method.

I finally remove all `store:Schema="YourSchema"` and `Schema="YourSchema"` in EDMX file, and I do it by write a `bat` file with `powershell command` as below, and execute the `bat` in the `Projec Pre-Build Event`:

```
powershell -Command "$varStr='store:Schema=""abcd""""'; $filePath='%~dp0SomeFolder\SomeFile.edmx'; (gc $filePath) -replace $varStr, '' | Out-File $filePath"
```

Comment: Why does the schema need to be removed? Why does it generate it this way?

Comment: `store:Schema="YourSchema"`  will specify specific DB name, so it cannot be generally connect to other DB.